# Multiple error codes for both front wheel speed sensors

Tags: obd-ii, dodge, abs, traction-control, wheel-speed-sensor

My ABS and traction control warning lights are on, and I'm getting the following codes: C1041, C1042, C1014, C101F, C1011, C101C. I'd replace the speed sensors but since I'm getting codes for both front wheels, I'm wondering if it could be a bigger problem. What could be causing this?

I'll also add that after first starting the car, the brake pedal sometimes pushes back at me for a second while moving. The traction control warning light is also on.

2013 Dodge Avenger, 105,000 miles

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Other than severe corrosion, damaged/broken reluctors, damaged sensors and wiring, maybe the electrical system is sketchy. Battery voltage should be around 12.5v, engine off, between 13.3v-15v, averaging around 14.5v. Some vehicle abs/tc/esc electronics are sensitive to voltage fluctuations outside a range that can wreak havoc with mystery error codes. The main electrical connections between battery, ground and fuse panels should be clean and free of corrosion.